# How to map datatype to set of that datatype

Tags: types, kotlin

The code:

```
abstract class DataContainer(public val path: String)
val preloaded: MutableMap<Class<out DataContainer>, HashSet<out DataContainer>> = hashMapOf()
```

I would like to know how to make Kotlin realize that the first `out DataContainer` is the same type as the second `out DataContainer`.
So that code like:

```
fun <D: DataContainer> get(clazz: Class<D>): HashSet<D> = preloaded[clazz] as HashSet<D>
```

Doesn't require `as HashSet<D>` (and isn't prone to casting errors).
I am new to Kotlin, so do link documentation if I've missed something.
Also, this code would be inside an `object` if it matters.

Comment: Basically, what you're trying to express is that each key and value in a map has a different type argument, and the type argument for each map key is the same as for the corresponding map value. Unfortunately Kotlin's type system is not rich enough to express such a relationship. You need to use the cast.

Comment: Java's type system is not rich enough to express this either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that what you want is feasible at a language level.

A cast in the `get` method isn't that bad as long as you can do it safely. The only way I can see to do that safely is to control the `put` method as well.

If you enforce that each key of type `D : DataContainer` will be paired with a key of type `Set<D>`, you can safely cast when getting. For instance you could something like this:

```
object DataContainerRegistry {

    private val preloaded: MutableMap<Class<out DataContainer>, HashSet<DataContainer>> = hashMapOf()

    fun put(dataContainer: DataContainer) {
        val set = preloaded.getOrDefault(dataContainer::class.java, HashSet())
        set.add(dataContainer)
        preloaded[dataContainer::class.java] = set
    }

    fun <D : DataContainer> get(clazz: Class<D>) = preloaded.getOrDefault(clazz, HashSet()) as Set<D>

}
```

The limitations of this method are:

1. only one class (`DataContainerRegistry` singleton in my example) will have direct access to the `preloaded` map
2. the `get` method will return only `Set`, not the mutable interface.

This way you know that nobody will mess up `preloaded` and each `Set` contained in it, and you can then cast light-heartedly.

Answer (score 0):

Part of this is a Java language fundamental.

As your example stands, imagine you have a collection of `Animal` objects. You can put `Cat` and `Dog` in there, but when it comes to pull out a `Cat` specifically, you have to assert that it is indeed a `Cat` by using the cast.

However if you are willing to constrain a particular instance of your collection to only dealing in `Cat` or `Dog`, then this works fine.

So, let's imagine we have those:

```
abstract class DataContainer(public val path: String)

abstract class CatDataContainer(path: String): DataContainer(path)

abstract class DogDataContainer(path: String): DataContainer(path)
```

That's just your DataContainer and two subclasses.

If we put a type parameter on a class that owns your map, we can do this:

```
class TypedContainerHolder1<D: DataContainer> {

    val preloaded: MutableMap<Class<out D>, HashSet<out D>> = hashMapOf()

    fun get(clazz: Class<D>): HashSet<out D>? = preloaded[clazz]
}

val typedContainerHolder1 = TypedContainerHolder1<CatDataContainer>()
```

Furthermore, we can arguably improve on that by limiting the map to identical key/value pair types. This also uses Kotlin's delegation.

```
class TypedContainerHolder2<D: DataContainer> {

    inner class PreloadedMap<MapType : D> : Map<Class<out MapType>, HashSet<out MapType>> by hashMapOf()

    private val preloaded = PreloadedMap<D>()

    fun get(clazz: Class<D>): HashSet<out D>? = preloaded[clazz]
}

val typedContainerHolder2 = TypedContainerHolder2<DogDataContainer>()
```

No casts, and a little more type safety once you've set it up. The question is whether your scenario allows this constraint.

Comment: I don't actually know how many subclasses of DataContainer there are, this is for a library, and the developer creates the subclass.

Comment: That's fine, but you need to figure out whether they need to be held in a *mixed* collection or not, i.e. a map that holds different subclasses together or a map that only holds ones of the same type, because that's the main thing that decides what you can do here.

Comment: The map will need to hold different subclasses together. What I meant with the first answer is that I would need a `TypedContainerHolder`  for each subclass of DataContainer, I would end up where I started (and with a lot more classes).